# Passing parameter to method in array.map

Tags: javascript, callback

How can i pass parameter to a method which is passed as parameter inside an array. map method.

```
var result = [1,2,3];
var updatedResult = result.map(modifierMethod);
function modifierMethod(cellValue){ return cellValue* dynamicValue}
```

I want to pass the dynamicValue into the modifierMethod while calling map method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use bind to add parameters to your function like this

```js
function mapping() { return arguments[0].multy * arguments[1] }

var b = [1,2,3,4,5]
const options = { multy: 5 }
var c = b.map(mapping.bind(null, options))

console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actiually I do not see any problems ... If I run the following code:

```
var result = [1,2,3];
var updatedResult = result.map(modifierMethod);
function modifierMethod(cellValue){ return cellValue * 2}
console.log(updatedResult);
```

It works properly as expected. Output is the following:

```
[ 2, 4, 6 ]
```

Maybe I do not understand your issue ?

Comment: Well the above definitely works. However I wanted the multiplier to be passed(as dynamic) rather than keep it static(=2, in your case).